# Efficiently storing membership time info in Clickhouse

Tags: sql, database, clickhouse

I'm trying to store/retrieve information of type 'entity X belonged to group Y from time T1 to time T2', where T2 can be actual date or this entity still belongs to group. Simplest implementation looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE membership
(
    `Group` FixedString(24),
    `Entity` FixedString(24),
    `StartDate` DateTime,
    `EndDate` DateTime,
    `TotalTimeSeconds` UInt32,
    `StillBelongs` Bool
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PRIMARY KEY Group
```

Information I want to retrieve looks like this:

- which entities belong (now) to group Y?
- which entities belonged to group Y at time T?
- which entities belonged to group Y longer than Z seconds?

The issue I have is that I'm supposed to update information in this table, for example once a day. In this process I might add some new entities to given groups (OK) or I have to set that given entity is no longer member of given group (ALTER and set EndDate/StillBelongs/TotalTimeSeconds). These ALTERs are heavy and inefficient, I suppose (and it looks like it from my tests).

Can you help me finding better implementation for this table? I guess I shouldn't store both `StartDate` and `EndDate` in one row, but have `Date` and `EventType`, where `EventType` is something like `StartBelong`, `EndBelong`. This way I don't need to update any rows, just add more of them. But then I'm not sure how to implement queries that easily achieve my goals? (I need those queries to be as quick as possible)

Thanks for any advice (I'm not experienced with Clickhouse).